# How to generate CRUD datagrid interface?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, datagrid, crud

Is there any open source library I can generate a datagrid interface from an RESTful api datasource?

For example if I have a database table "Products" with `id,name` and a REST endpoint `http://example.com/api/products`, that returns json data id and name, is there any simple way I can generate a CRUD interface to create/read/update/delete products from the database?

I am thinking something like [datatables editor](https://editor.datatables.net/) but this is not open source and I cannot find anything similar that would work with a restful datasource.

Is it possible to use google sheets as a CRUD interface for a rest datasource?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you dont need to manipulate the data on the client side I'd just use some javascipt to make an AJAX request to `example.com/api/products` and then parse it, put it into a table and add some buttons with callbacks and stuff to do the CRUD stuff